# Angular 2 to 4/5/6: What are some things to know/do/check before upgrading?

Tags: angular, typescript, model-view-controller, components

I have to convert an *Angular 2* project to *Angular 6*. It has its backend made with *WebAPI* which is connected to *SQL Server*. I think it is based on the *MVC*.

Also, I have to make the application modular *i.e.* I have to combine all the components that are dependent on each other: make a module for them and then import that module in app.module.

So what are some things that I should know/do/check before upgrading to *Angular 2 to 6*?

And how will I check which component is dependent on some other component because the app has 250+ components?

Comment: Note: For your next question please consider not posting three distinct questions into a single one ;)

Comment: Thanks! I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updating:

There is *so* much going on between these versions, I recommend *slowly* moving forward along each of the major versions (2->4->5->6).

You should check out https://update.angular.io/, that site will tell you what to look out for for each of these version jumps.

#### Modularity:

Concerning modularity: ngModules was introduces before the final version of Angular (2), you can probably consider upgrading and ngModule consolidation two distinct projects.

#### Dependency checks:

You could use a tool like https://github.com/compodoc/ngd to visualize your dependency graph.